# Why are branch instructions faster than jump instructions?

Tags: assembly, avr

Looking at the [amtel avr instruction set](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf), I noticed that a branch instruction takes 2 cycles if executed and 1 if not, while a jump instruction takes 3 cycles.

Why is this?

Comment: I read that the jmp allows access to the entire program memory. Could this be why?

Comment: Also if I want to branch but without a condition how would i do this instead of jmp

Comment: `JMP` is simply a 4 byte instruction. Notice that `RJMP`, being a 2 byte instruction, executes in 2 clocks.

Comment: @Jester: Can RJMP goto a label instead of a specific number of instructions (I know its the same thing but can what I mean is can i just write the label?)

Comment: Yes, the assembler will figure out the distance for you. It should be within 2k range, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this comes from the OP-Code length. the `JMP` instruction is 32bit instruction because it has to read the address from a separate word. This reading costs the additional clock cycle.

branches and relative jump `rjmp` and indirect jump `ijmp` are 16bit instructions that are also executed in 2 clock cycles.